# Sign windows electron build on macOS (Catalina)

Tags: windows, macos, docker, electron, electron-builder

On Mojave I had electron builder set up with osslsigncode to create windows builds working with an EV certificate. outlined [here](https://www.electron.build/tutorials/code-signing-windows-apps-on-unix)

Since 10.15/Catalina this is no longer possible as the build process uses Wine to create the nsis installer package.  Wine is 32bit, support for which has been dropped.

The new [recommended](https://www.electron.build/multi-platform-build) build process is to use a docker container to perform the build (essentially using linux).  I am trying to create a docker image with osslsigncode without success so far, and am wondering if I will ever be able to get the EV usb dongle visible in a docker container.

Anyone have any solutions - other than build on windows!

Comment: It's all a big pain. I never got Windows code signing to work on OSX using `Electron Builder`. What I have ended up doing it buidling on OSX, then running `Windows` in emulation with`WMWare Fusion` signing using the free utility [kSign](https://support.ksoftware.net/support/solutions/articles/17170-how-do-i-use-ksign-to-digitally-sign-files-). Not too painful – but I already had VMWare/Windows installed. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: Why is there a need to cross compile rather than building on the host platform itself?  The hassle this creates must make this untenable?

Comment: Because it won't compile on windows without fixing/changing a load of npm modules and *nix scripts I use.  App is basically a packaged PWA, so 99% of testing done in browser - so other than signing, its much easier to cross compile...

Comment: @NickH247 finally got it done ?

Comment: no, I used a linux box in the end...